# Extract array from text file

Tags: c#, arrays, file, extract

I have a huge (~500K) text file, which looks like this:

```
{   // H-20e180a.wav 
    {-7,5,-4,-1,-9,2,-5,-1,2,-12,12,-33,34,-48,41,-40,16,20,730,4751,3861},
    {-7,5,-4,-1,-9,2,-5,-1,2,-12,12,-33,34,-48,41,-40,16,20,}
}
```

(NOTE: in the actual file there is some extra clutter, and the array-pairs are much longer each ~140 elts).

I am looking to create a C# / .NET routine that allows me to extract a pair of arrays:

```
int [] [] elev_neg20__azi_180 = ArraysForLocation( -20, 180 );
```

What would be my basic strategy?

From my days of coding BASIC, I would read in one line at a time, looking for '// H', then extract the 2 numbers, and if they match I would process the next two lines.  But things have probably moved on since then!

I'm guessing that there is no shortcut to reading through the entire file...

Comment: I don't think int[][] is a pair of arrays. What exactly your file looks like and what is your desired output? You showed us a method and didnt tell what it does. Please be more speciffic.

Answer (score 2):

> *From my days of coding BASIC, I would read in one line at a time, looking for '// H', then extract the 2 numbers, and if they match I would process the next two lines.*

Approach it the same way.  Using [`System.IO.StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.StreamReader.aspx) you can repeatedly [`ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) until you find the desired section, read the next two lines of data, and [`Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.close.aspx).  Then [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) the comma separated values and [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx).

And actually you probably wouldn't explicitly call `Close`.  The `StreamReader` class implements `IDisposable` so a best practice is to wrap it in a `using` statement (which automatically calls `Dispose` which will close the stream).

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("somefile.txt"))
{
   string line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Parsing a string containing a line of your data could be done like this:

```
string line = "{-7,5,-4,-1,-9,2,-5,-1,2,-12,12,-33,34,-48,41,-40,16,20,730,4751,3861},";

var regex = new Regex("[{},]");
int[] ints = regex.Replace(line, " ").Trim().
                   Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

An option for returning the arrays from a method is to use `out` values.  That way your normal return value could be used to indicate success.  A method signature like this:

```
public bool ArraysForLocation(int x, int y, out int[] array1, out int[] array2)
```

could be called like this:

```
int[] a1;
int[] a2;
bool ok = ArraysForLocation(-20, 180, out a1, out a2);
```

> *I'm guessing that there is no shortcut to reading through the entire file...*

You won't read the entire file unless what you are seeking is at the tail.  You are *streaming* the data so only a line is read at a time.  Unless the file content is sorted so that you could do a binary search with [`FileStream.Seek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx), then you'll need to read through the file until you find the data you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string.Split(Char[]) method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

This method returns an array of strings.

The char parameter is the delimiter you want to split on. So you would call it once to split your long string into the two arrays you want, and then on each one split on the comma to get the respective arrays of individual values.  After that you could convert the strings to int if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing much lookup and speed is more important than memory you might want to process the file once and put the information into a dictionary. That way lookup is very fast and you only have to read the file once.

Here's some code that will parse data like the example you gave:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filename = "example.txt";

        Dictionary<string, int[][]> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int[][]>();

        BuildMyDataDictionary(filename, myDictionary);

        //lookup via key
        int x = 20;
        int y = 180;
        string key = string.Format("{0}.{1}", x, y);
        int[][] values = myDictionary[key];

        //print the values to check
        foreach (int[] array in values)
            foreach (int i in array)
                Console.Write(i + ", ");
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void BuildMyDataDictionary(string filename, Dictionary<string, int[][]> myDictionary)
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            string line = r.ReadLine();
            // read through the file line by line and build the dictionary
            while (line != null)
            {
                Regex regx = new Regex(@"//\s*H\-(\d*)\w(\d*)");
                Match m = regx.Match(line);
                if (m.Success)
                {
                    // make a key of the two parts int 1 and int2 separated by a "."
                    string key = string.Format("{0}.{1}", m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2]);

                    // continue reading the block
                    List<int[]> intList = new List<int[]>();
                    line = r.ReadLine();
                    while (!Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^\s*\}"))
                    {
                        Regex regex = new Regex("[{},]");
                        intList.Add(regex.Replace(line, " ").Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Select(int.Parse).ToArray());
                        line = r.ReadLine();
                    }
                    myDictionary.Add(key, intList.ToArray());
                }
                line = r.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The example file I tested with was:

```
{   // H-20e180a.wav 
    {-7,5,-4,-1,-9,2,-5,-1,2,-12,12,-33,34,-48,41,-40,16,20,730,4751,3861},
    {-7,5,-4,-1,-9,2,-5,-1,2,-12,12,-33,34,-48,41,-40,16,20,}
}
{   // H-21e181a.wav 
    {-7,5,-4,-1,-9,2,-5,-1,2,-12,12,-33,34,-48,41,-40,16,20,730,4751,3861},
    {-7,5,-4,-1,-9,2,-5,-1,2,-12,12,-33,34,-48,41,-40,16,20,}
    {-7,5,-4,-1,-9,2,-5,-1,2,-12,12,-33,34,-48,41,-40,16,20,730,4751,3861},
}
```

I borrowed the int[] parsing and creation from jltrem above.

Comment: Your StreamReader should be in a `using` statement.  Otherwise you need to try/catch/finally with a Dispose in the finally.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it would be best to add some try/catch/finally 

I had the using statement above where I cut outside the main 
using System.IO;

Comment: I'm not talking about a [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).  You need a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) around your StreamReader.  You aren't closing the file stream, and even if you were an exception would cause it to not be properly disposed.  A using block handles this for you. `using (var r = new StreamReader(filename)) { ... }` is what you need to add. (this was explained in my answer)

Comment: I've updated my code with a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). thanks! @jltrem